# I can't see the categories after migration to magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I migrate my store to magento2 (CE), but now I cant see the categories section, I get a error called: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.

In my magento 1.9.x I had 2 stores, they are migrated but I can't see the categories part.

many thanks

Alfredo

Comment: Did you migrated the stores or created them again in Magento 2 and migrated only catalog data?

Comment: Please check admin side, stores are exist or not, than check with category page category belongs to that store or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check table `store_group`and make sure the root catagories (`root_category_id` field) is assigned to the store (`website_id` field)

In case: Root Catalog (ID 1) & Default Category (ID 2) has been deleted in the database. You can re-add it by running the following SQL commands:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`row_id`, `entity_id`, `created_in`, `updated_in`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 2147483647, 3, 0, '2018-08-30 07:14:33', '2018-08-30 09:40:41', '1', 0, 0, 5),
(2, 2, 1, 2147483647, 3, 1, '2018-08-30 07:14:33', '2018-08-30 07:14:33', '1/2', 1, 1, 0);

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `row_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 69, 0, 1, 1),
(2, 46, 0, 2, 1),
(3, 69, 0, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `row_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 45, 0, 1, 'Root Catalog'),
(2, 45, 0, 2, 'Default Category'),
(3, 52, 0, 2, 'PRODUCTS');
```

Answer (score 0):

Open DB of same and check for an entry in `store` table then check under `catalog_category_entity_int` that store id under this matches stores id under `store` table. There may be possible that before migration you forgot to delete categories or stores from existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the issue is resolved after these steps:
[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]
And then Clean cache and open catalog->default category and enable that and save again